# IOS Add right button to navigation bar not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

It works with ViewController that does not have tab bar but not with tab bar.
Also, this is the first view controller in the story board.

```
UIImage *bookmarkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark"];

//create the button and assign the image
UIButton *bookmarkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

 //set the frame of the button to the size of the image (see note below)
bookmarkButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, bookmarkImage.size.width,      bookmarkImage.size.height);
        [bookmarkButton setImage:bookmarkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

bookmarkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addFavorite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
bookmarkButton.imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

//create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:bookmarkButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarItem2;
```

Comment: I guess that link has been helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a bit of problem understanding your question, but from I can gather, it seems that which ever class you trying to add your button isn't held in a `UINavigationController`.

I'm not sure how you instantiate this class (ClassX) but it should be done similar to this:

```
ClassX *temp = [[ClassX alloc] init....];

UINavigationController *control = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:temp];
```

Then display controls view.

Answer (score 0):

First impression,i think the problem is cause by `UIButton *bookmarkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];` , but i am not very sure . 
And if you want , you can modify like this . it does work.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My NavigationBar"] autorelease];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 70, 30)];

    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bookmark.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithCustomView:button];

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
    [navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBar];

    [buttonItem release];
    [button release];
}
```